# How might I determine the XPath of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, xpath

In JavaScript, supposing I have a reference to an element, how do I retrieve an XPath expression that would select it?

Is there something like `objElement.xpath`?

Comment: Language? Framework? Platform?

Comment: modified my question... i'm thinking javascript

Comment: Got a solution @ this link
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4349

Comment: @Annibigi: please post that as an answer to your own question so we can vote that up.

Answer (score 2):

Since Annibigi doesn't want to post the solution, I'll do it: See [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4349).

Answer (score 0):

This is not XPATH related, but just to show you how you can get the parent/child relationship with a damn simple while loop.

```
var pathAt = function(node) {
    var stack = [];
    while(node.parentNode !== null) {
        stack.unshift(node.tagName);
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return stack.join('/');
}

// Usage : pathAt(document.getElementBy('moo'));
// Outputs : "HTML/BODY/CENTER/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD"
```

Comment: You also need to include the index for elements which can appear multiple times as a child (think DIV or P).